# SSIS package with trigger on the table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS package on Sql server 2008 which inserts data into a table in a transaction. There is a trigger on the table. That is causing the following exception while inserting -

Bulk Insert with another outstanding result set should be run with XACT_ABORT on

I am using OLEDB. How can I fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you disable the trigger?

Here is a thread on this issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/5be1bab7-74c1-4d1c-a6f7-7d0c925dce12